# How to retrieve the name of a list passed to a function using lapply

Tags: r, lapply

```
Z = data.frame(var1 = c(1,2,3,4,5), var2 = LETTERS[1:5])

testfun <- function(x){
  print(x) # prints the data
  # but how to get names of the list coming in?
  return(NULL)
}

res = lapply(Z, testfun)
```

I want to access variables "var1" and "var2" inside testfun. How do I retrieve those variables inside testfun? Does lapply even pass that information? `colnames(x)` does not work.

Comment: With `lapply`, you're passing individual columns to the function. I'm not sure having variable name makes sense in this case. Unless, you want to manipulate `Z` according to the variable names, in which case I would do `lapply(names(Z), FUN = function(x, my.df) {}, my.df = Z)`. Another option would be to use `mapply(Z, names(Z), FUN = function(x, y) {...})`.

Comment: Maybe (horrors! :-) ) write a `for` loop instead. `for(j in 1:length(Z)) {print(Z[[j]]) ; print(names(Z)[j]) } `

Comment: Thanks Roman. That is what Roland pointed out, and I knew I could do that. But I was not sure about passing a large Z by copy (if it copies at every call) to testfun.

Yup Carl. Could have done that, :) stored in an env, and called it from testfun. Just wanted to keep my code very lean, and do as much as possible within functions and function calls. This is a pretty large production-level code base and would help in readability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `lapply` doesn't pass this information to the function. You could `lapply` along the names and use subsetting to get the list content inside the function.

```
testfun <- function(nam, mylist){
  print(nam) # prints the names
  mylist[[nam]] #get list content using subsetting
}

res <- lapply(names(Z), testfun, mylist=Z)
# [1] "var1"
# [1] "var2"

res
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] A B C D E
# Levels: A B C D E
```

Comment: Thanks. This means that the whole Z is passed to testfun every time then?

Comment: Actually, after some testing, I don't think it's passed every time. The arguments passed by the ellipses become local variables the environment of the `lapply` call and the actual evaluation of the function get's them from this environment. How many copies are made, smarter people than me would need to check.

Comment: Yes. I am not sure how to make that check, but I will try to do it. I have to pass a large data frame as a param, but I am not manipulating anything in the data frame(just subsetting columns to work on), in which case I think copies are not made. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you are concerned about performance you should use a data.table solution.

Comment: The operation on Z is row-by-row (i.e. no grouping), but new cols for Z are generated in testfun using some aggregation methods. So within testfun, I am using data table to run the aggregation jobs, but for the lapply I did not use data table. There might be some perf improvements if I did that too, need to check it. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @Roland's answer, I would just do the apply on `1:length(Z)`, and pass the list and the list names to the function.

```
nams <- names(Z)
testfun <- function(i,Z,nams){
print(Z[[i]])
print(nams[i])}

res <- lapply(1:length(Z),testfun,Z=Z,nams=nams)
```

If you just want to preserve the labels, you can use `llply` from `plyr` package.

```
testfun <- function(x){x}
res <- llply(Z,testfun)
res
```

result will be:

```
> res
$var1
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

$var2
[1] A B C D E
Levels: A B C D E
```

Comment: Thanks @Zhenlei. Appreciate your response, but I have used Roland's method. plyr package was slow the last time I checked, and I have large data frame with almost a million rows.